# Can send but not receive in C (server), from Android (client), after changing networks IP on client

Tags: java, android, c, sockets, tcp

Edit: Before anything else, I know what TCP and UDP are, and the differences, but then how can one explain that I am able to receive on Client from Server, but not send, as seen below...?

I made a server app in C, and a client app in Java, which I deployed to Android.
I have a strange problem, which I am not able to overcome.

When my phone IP changes (for example when switching to Mobile network, from Wifi, or viceversa), the application in C is no longer able to receive data, just to send, even though the phone sends it, without any errors.

This does not happen when reconnecting to the same network.

I tried many things, and ended up with this, in C:

```
void *receive_thread(){
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    struct sockaddr_in dest; /* socket info about the machine connecting to us */
    struct sockaddr_in serv; /* socket info about our server */
    int mysocket;            /* socket used to listen for incoming connections */
    socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));           /* zero the struct before filling the fields */
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* set the type of connection to TCP/IP */
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* set our address to any interface */
    serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUMRCV);           /* set the server port number */    

    mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //fcntl(mysocket, F_SETFD, O_NONBLOCK);

    /* bind serv information to mysocket */
    bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    /* start listening, allowing a queue of up to 1 pending connection */
    listen(mysocket, 1);

    int consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
    while(consocket){
        //socklen_t fromlen;
        //fromlen = sizeof inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr);
        char receivemsg[128];

        int rlen = recv(consocket, &receivemsg, 128, 0); //receive data
        int err = errno;
        //printf("recv error: %d\n", err);
        printf("Received string: %s from %s \n", receivemsg, inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
        if(rlen > 0){
            receivemsg[rlen] = '\0';
            if(comparestr(KEY, receivemsg) == 1){
                printf("Local client\n");
                incrementor++;
            } else if(comparestr(KEY, receivemsg) == 2){
                printf("Remote client\n");
                incrementor--;
            } else {
                printf("Wrong key!\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf("Care!!!! Receiving: %d \n", rlen);
        }
        close(consocket);
        consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
    }
    printf("Receive thread ended!\n");
    receive_thread_up = 0;
}

void *send_thread(){
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    struct sockaddr_in dest; /* socket info about the machine connecting to us */
    struct sockaddr_in serv; /* socket info about our server */
    int mysocket;            /* socket used to listen for incoming connections */
    socklen_t socksize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    memset(&serv, 0, sizeof(serv));           /* zero the struct before filling the fields */
    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* set the type of connection to TCP/IP */
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* set our address to any interface */
    serv.sin_port = htons(PORTNUMSND);           /* set the server port number */

    mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /* bind serv information to mysocket */
    bind(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    /* start listening, allowing a queue of up to 1 pending connection */
    listen(mysocket, 1);

    int consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
    while(consocket){
        //printf("Incoming connection from %s - sending string\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
        int slen = send(consocket, KEY, 3*sizeof(KEY), 0); //send data
        if(slen>0)printf("Sent string: %s to %s \n", KEY, inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr));
        else {
            printf("Care!!! Sending: %d \n", slen);
        }       
        close(consocket);
        consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);
    }
    printf("Send thread ended!\n");
    send_thread_up = 0;
}
```

And this, in Java:

```
public static int sendString(String str) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Sending string: " + str);
    out.println(str);
    return 0;
}

public static String receiveString(){
    String s = " ";
    try {
        s = in.readLine();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.out.println("Socket Exception: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException on receive: " + e);
    }
    System.out.println("Received string: " + s);
    return s;
}
public static String reverseString(String str){
    String newStr = " ";
    newStr = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
    return newStr;
}
```

My guess is that recv gets stuck, hence why I tried to add

```
fcntl(mysocket, F_SETFD, O_NONBLOCK);
```

, which after not working, I commented it.
Maybe use UDP socket? I may run into issues like message not arriving, or not being whole.
Suggestions to improve my code are also welcome!

Here is the output in C:

```
Thread: No connection, waiting...
Sent string: I4mP4ssw0rd7 to 192.168.1.2
Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
 from 192.168.1.2
Local client
Sent string: I4mP4ssw0rd7 to 192.168.1.2
Thread: Local connection!
Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
 from 192.168.1.2
Local client
Sent string: I4mP4ssw0rd7 to 192.168.1.2
Sent string: I4mP4ssw0rd7 to 87.edited
Sent string: I4mP4ssw0rd7 to 87.edited
Sent string: I4mP4ssw0rd7 to 87.edited
Sent string: I4mP4ssw0rd7 to 87.edited
Sent string: I4mP4ssw0rd7 to 87.edited
```

And here is the output from Java:

```
03-18 22:52:45.831  13899-13899/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Connected!
03-18 22:52:49.375  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Connected locally!
03-18 22:52:49.585  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:52:54.900  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Sending string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:52:54.910  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Connected locally!
03-18 22:52:54.970  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:53:00.265  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Sending string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:53:00.285  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Connected locally!
03-18 22:53:00.315  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:53:05.631  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Sending string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:53:05.631  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Connected remotely!
03-18 22:53:05.851  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:53:11.266  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Sending string: 7dr0wss4Pm4I
03-18 22:53:11.286  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Connected remotely!
03-18 22:53:11.516  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:53:16.912  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Sending string: 7dr0wss4Pm4I
03-18 22:53:16.932  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Connected remotely!
03-18 22:53:17.162  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:53:22.547  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Sending string: 7dr0wss4Pm4I
03-18 22:53:22.567  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Connected remotely!
03-18 22:53:23.198  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
03-18 22:53:28.933  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Sending string: 7dr0wss4Pm4I
03-18 22:53:28.933  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Connected remotely!
03-18 22:53:29.113  13899-13920/willymatica.alarmapp1 I/System.out﹕ Received string: I4mP4ssw0rd7
```

Comment: If the phone changed IPs you shouldn't be able to send or receive.  A TCP socket requires a connection to a specific IP.  Most likely you aren't really sending-  you're sending to a dead connection and missed the fact that the socket was closed on the other end.

Comment: The connection is dropped after each send and after each receive. I am 100% positive that I am able to send, because when there is no connection on the phone, I get a "disconnected" status, while when there is, I have a send and a receive message. On the server side, I only have a send message (while the phone has network), and "no connection" status, when the phone has no connection.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is connection oriented. Once a TCP connection is establised you get what is known as a socket pair. A Socket pair is the combination of the source ip adress and source port and destination ip address and destination port. The connection is uniquely identified by those 4 parameters.

During the whole session the same ip adresses and ports will be used.

So if one network interface is no longer available, you have a problem, because each network interface will have a ip address, if it is no longer available a different one cannot be chosen anymore by the TCP connection.

TCP does not support changing IP adresses on either end of the connection.

It will take quite a long time to detect that there is a problem. You think you are still able to send, but, TCP will retransmit several times and eventually you will see that the send fails. This takes even e few minutes. Depending on your socket being blocking or not you will notice that send would block in the error condition where the IP@ has changed. This is like broken wire from TCP's point of view.

Comment: Added the outputs of both Java and C, so you can see

Comment: I am sending, from the server, and have a confirmation from client that it receives, after IP changed

Comment: No you don't. after IP@ change it is impossible that you still receive.

Comment: The only way to really know what is going on is to put wireshark is to use wireshark to watch what is coming on the wire. The traces by the application  don't prove where the packets are coming from.

Comment: It's a bit complicated for me, at the moment, to set up wireshark to monitor the wireles traffic. 

Still, from the outputs, you can see that the packet sent goes to a whole different IP "Sent string: I4mP4ssw0rd7 to 87.edited", than it did initially, and the client also receives it.

Comment: And also, since I have "listen(mysocket, 1);" on my socket, that means that I should be able to receive connections from different sources, on first parameter (mysocket), with a backlog queue (2nd parameter) of a maximum of 1 client, that can be accepted, with "int consocket = accept(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &socksize);".

Comment: If you go through accept again, you are establishing a new connection.

Comment: Indeed, which seem to happen in the case of sending, but not receiving, on the server, and hence the reason I posted this. I added the codes, so you can see what happens in both receive and send threads